# Proving $\mathbb{C}[x,y]/(x+2y^2)$ is isomorphic to a subring of $\mathbb{C}[s,t,u]/(st + u^2)$

Tags: ring-theory

Since it's been a while since I did my course in basic abstract algebra, as I am playing around with homemade examples trying to revise stuff and making sure that I still get the very most fundamental, I just wanted to know if the following is legitimate.

Consider the two rings $R_1 = \mathbb{C}[x,y]/(x+2y^2)$ and $R_2 = \mathbb{C}[s,t,u]/(st + u^2)$. I make the claim that $R_1$ is isomorphic to a subring of $R_2$ by means of the injective morphism $f : R_1 \rightarrow R_2$ defined by
$$x \mapsto st , \qquad y \mapsto \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} u .$$
Then, it is clear that $f(x)+2(f(y))^2 = 0$.

Is this a legitimate proof and course of action, or is there some silly mistake that I am making?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: From $f(x)+2(f(y))^2=0$, we see that $f$ is a homomorphism. Maybe also elaborate why $f$ is injective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this a legitimate proof and course of action

Yes, it is legitimate, but I would say it this way: It is a property of polynomial algebras that this grants you a homomorphism $f:\mathbb C[x,y]\to R_2$ given the choices you made.

The first homomorphism theorem says that $\mathbb C[x,y]/\ker(f)\cong \mathrm{Im}(f)\subseteq R_2$.

The only thing left for you to decide is whether or not $\ker(f)=(x+2y^2)$.  Certainly by your choice, you have already guaranteed that $(x+2y^2)\subseteq \ker(f)$, but proving the reverse containment would be necessary for complete success.

Comment: Awesome! :D

Err-... If I may ask your help again on that particular point, since I just keep going around in circles as I try to prove that on my own, how would one do that?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know a simple way, although I think it's true.  There's probably a standard way to do it from algebraic geometry, but I don't know it.

Comment: Wouldn't it work if you take the subring generated by $\{1,st,u \}$ (which equals $\text{im}(f)$), construct an inverse morphism $f^{-1}$ by $st \mapsto x$ and $u \mapsto \sqrt{2} z$ and then simply conclude that since the composition $f^{-1} \circ f = \text{id}$, $R_1$ is isomorphic to $\text{im}(f)$? Or is there some circular reasoning involved there?

Comment: It doesn't resolve the problem. How do you even know you have a map $f:R_1\to R_2$?  As of the part where I left off, we only have a map from $\mathbb C[x,y]/I$ where $I\supseteq (x+2y^2)$.  What you're talking about would work if you knew your original ideal for a map from $R_1\to R_2$ was valid, though. The problem is though I don't think it's safe to assume the assignment really is a homomorphism without justifying it like I'm trying to do above.  There could be a lemma I don't know, of course.

Comment: Well, than, I think we'll leave it at that. I feel more or less satisfied for my purposes. Thanks again. :)